# How do you solve this logarithmic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

While reading through my textbook, I came across this particular equation:
$$ x = x\log (y) + \log (y) $$
But they solve it by doing this:
$$ x = x\log (y) + \log (y) $$
$$ x = (x + 1)\log(y) $$
$$ \frac {x}{x+1} = \log(y) $$
$$ y = 10^{\frac{x}{x+1}} $$
Which is fine, but I don't understand why they didn't do it like this:
$$ x = x\log (y) + \log (y) $$
$$ x=\log(y^x)+\log(y) $$
$$ x=\log(y^{2x}) $$
$$ x=2x\log(y) $$
$$ \frac{x}{2x}=\log(y) $$
$$ y=10^{\frac{x}{2x}} $$
I'm confused over which one is correct.

Comment: Yep, I feel like an idiot! Thanks, shost71 and MPW!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have got an error:
$ x = log(y^x) + log(y) = log(y^x\cdot y) = log(y^{x+1})$

Answer (score 0):

You've made an error.

$\log y^x +\log y$ is $\log y^{x+1}$, not $\log y^{2x}$

Answer (score 0):

When you do
$$ log(y^x) + log(y) $$
this equals:
$$ log(y^x \cdot y) = log(y^{x+1}) $$

which gives $ y = 10^{\frac{x}{x+1}} $